# Append to the end of an element with querySelector

Tags: javascript

How do I get the `nodeValue` when using the `querySelector`?

http://jsbin.com/cavowacaho/1/edit?html,js,console

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input");

input.nodeValue += " thanks!";
```

Comment: Exactly like that, but the value of an `<input>` element is not stored in its `nodeValue`, if it's what you're trying to do.

Comment: For inputs it's `input.value`

Comment: No, i need to get the ```nodeValue``` so I can append a span at the end..

Comment: @Michael, assuming your `.input` selector matches an `<input>` element, such an element is not supposed to have children. Appending a `<span>` element inside it will only result in invalid HTML (and you should use `appendChild()` to do that in the first place, not `nodeValue`).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, I would like to append at the end, not within. Otherwise i would use ```innerHTML```

Comment: Then if you want to insert the `<span>` element after the `<input>`, I don't see what the `nodeValue` of the latter would bring you. Can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/koyopegigo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The input is ```<input type="text" class="input"/>```, I would like to make it ```<input type="text" class="input"/> Thanks!```,

Comment: @Alexey Lebedev, thanks thats what i'm looking for! I really do not see what is unclear and why this is downvoted....

Comment: @Alexey, your code appends the `<span>` element to the end of the `<input>`'s parent, not after the `<input>` itself. It will only work if the `<input>` element is the last child of its parent. Michael, that was not clear at all I'm afraid, especially given the DOM properties you were trying to use.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that is true, my question was how can I use ```nodeValue``` via ```querySelector```? Because i know if I had access to that I would just append to the end.

Comment: @Michael, I don't think I can say this any better: *`nodeValue` does not do what you think it does and will not help you with this problem.* Note that Alexey's implementation, though incomplete, never uses it.

Comment: I would like to get the element and append to the end of it, I've updated the question title. I wrongly thought nodeValue would be beneficial.

Comment: It is confusing and ambiguous to say "append to the end of an element". You can either append **inside** the element as a child (but not in the case of an `input` element), or append to the element's **text content** (but not in the case of an `input` element), or append to the **value** of the input element, or append **after** the element as a sibling. Maybe it would be most helpful if you provided a screenshot of how things should look after the append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `outerHTML` which worked fine, this also prevents against appending to the end of the element's parent - which `appendChild` would do.

http://jsbin.com/mezemosuye/1/edit?html,js,output